# How can I match an empty list of tuples?

Tags: list, f#, tuples

The following function gives a compilation error at the point I try to match an empty list:

```
let rec tuplesToList (acc: int list) (remaining: int*int list) =
    match remaining with
    | [] -> acc
    | (a, b) :: tail -> tuplesToList (a :: b :: acc)
```

The error is:

```
This expression was expected to have type int * int list but here has type 'a list
```

This works fine when `remaining` is a simple list of `int`s rather than tuples.  How can I match an empty list of tuples?

Comment: You shouldn't have edited your question. It no longer makes sense in light of the answers. I'm rolling it back.

Comment: Alternatively you could use [List.collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370406.aspx) ``let inline tuplesToList xs = xs |> List.collect (fun (a,b) -> [a;b])``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` is just fine to match an empty list of tuples. But according to your type annotation, `remaining` is not a list of tuples, it's a tuple containing an int and an int list. A list of tuples would be `(int*int) list`. `int * int list` is parsed as `int * (int list)`, not `(int * int) list`.

If you fix the type, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to sepp2k's observation, you've also forgotten the second parameter (`tail`) in the recursive call. Also, your code works fine without any type annotations whatsoever:

```
let rec tuplesToList acc remaining =
  match remaining with
  | [] -> List.rev acc //reverse to preserve original order
  | (a, b) :: tail -> tuplesToList (a :: b :: acc) tail
```

Comment: ...should also say, I wanted to reverse the list as well, so I've left that out.